# How to restrict access to rows of my query based on a contacts table of user ids

Tags: mysql

I have a query that produces a result like this:

[image: desired output]

The data is sorted by date DESC, then by time DESC, but also the common 'markers_name' elements are chunked together. (They're only chunked together for each date).

To do this I get the list of `MAX(time)` values for every combination of `(markers_id, date)` in `conditions`, then join that list to the row set I am getting from the present query, and use the `MAX(time)` values for sorting:

```
SELECT
  m.name AS markers_name,
  c.time AS conditions_time,
  c.date AS conditions_date,
  s.name AS station_name
FROM markers m
  INNER JOIN conditions c ON c.markers_id = m.id
  INNER JOIN station s    ON c.station_id = s.id
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      markers_id,
      date,
      MAX(time) AS time
    FROM conditions
    GROUP BY
      markers_id,
      date
  ) mx ON c.markers_id = mx.markers_id AND c.date = mx.date
ORDER BY
  c.date DESC,
  mx.time DESC,
  m.name DESC,
  c.time DESC
```

**Now I need to restrict user access to some of the rows.**
The conditions table has a 'private' column. If 'private' is set to 1 only some people are allowed to see the query row.  The people that can see it include the person that created the conditions report and that person's contacts. The conditions table has a 'user_id', which contains the id of the person that created the conditions report. The contacts are obtained from a 'contacts' table which has two fields: 'user_id' and 'friend_id'.  I have the user_id of the person requesting the information.

To restate another way, I need to do something like this:

1. Do the query above, but also check to see if c.private is set to one.
2. If c.private is set to one use c.user_id to get that user's 'friend_id's from the contacts table.
3. If the user_id of the person requesting the information matches c.user_id or any of c.user_id's friends return the query row.  If not, don't return that row or return something that indicates that the row is private (I could have a markers_name with the name "Private" in the database, for example.

If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them.  I struggled with this all day yesterday.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly just adding a filter like this would be enough:

```
…
WHERE c.Private <> 1
   OR c.user_id = @user_id
   OR c.user_id IN (
     SELECT friend_id
     FROM contacts WHERE user_id = @user_id
   )
```

where `@user_id` is the ID of the person requesting the info.

This would prohibit the private rows from appearing in the output where inappropriate.

If, however, you'd rather like them to be there but be marked as `Private` (for being dealt with later in the client or something like that), you could use that filter as a column in your SELECT clause:

```
SELECT
  NOT (
    c.Private <> 1
    OR c.user_id = @user_id
    OR c.user_id IN (
      SELECT friend_id
      FROM contacts WHERE user_id = @user_id
    )
  ) AS IsPrivate,
  …
FROM …
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  I just tried tried this, but I got an error in the where clause.  I will try debugging it tomorrow morning and let you know what I find.  Thanks again.

Comment: My error was due to not using single quotes around $userid.  I tried your first answer and it works great!  Thanks for providing the details on how to do it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have similar tables to play around with, so I'm writing this for you to try out, alright? Here is the `WHERE` clause for you to add to your query:

```
WHERE
    -- all non-1 valued `private` columns are public, right? remove if not
    c.private <> 1 
    -- all private but @user_id is entitled to view
    OR (
        c.private = 1 
        AND (
             (c.user_id = @user_id) -- requestor is creator
             OR (
                 EXISTS (
                     SELECT ct.friend_id 
                     FROM contacts ct
                     WHERE ct.user_id = c.user_id
                     AND friend_id = @user_id
                 ) -- requestor is a friend of the creator
                )
            )
       )
```

Again, I wasn't able to test this.. I'll leave that up to you for now.. so please let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot tomorrow.

Comment: I tried this and it works fine in phpMyAdmin (I replaced '@user_id' with 104).  Then I tried this code in my php file and it doesn't work (I replaced '@user_id' with $userid).  This is the error I'm seeing:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
             OR (
                 EXISTS (
                     SELECT ct.req' at line 16

Comment: I hope I don't confuse things further, but I feel I should explain something or else you might be puzzled by my error: where you have ct.friend_id I am now using ct.requestee and where you have ct. user_id I have ct.requester.

Comment: I would need your help posting the code where you changed/used $userid :: just a note, for variables to be evaluated within a string, the string must be enclosed with double quotes `"` and not single quotes `"`

Comment: Sorry Nonym.  I got it to work just fine, thanks!!  I needed to put single quotes around my php variable $userid.

Comment: I wanted to mark both answers as "this is the answer I will accept", but stack overflow won't allow me to do this.  I do want everyone reading this post to know that both answers work though (they are very similar answers in fact).

Comment: @user418775 - don't worry about it. just glad to have helped :D

Comment: Thanks Nonym.  I actually want to add one more enhancement to this query, but it's probably best to ask another question, rather than complicating things by adding it here.  If you wouldn't mind taking a look that would be very helpful.  I will post it later today.  Cheers